# Force app update through market, as if user clicks "Update"

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know, if there is some kind of "Intent" or something, to force the market to update a user-installed app programmatically. Personally, I assume this is a security risk, so I would guess there is no way, but maybe someone knows a workaround.

Comment: Not possible unless the user selected "Update automatically" while installing the app

Comment: One thing, that came to my mind, was emulating the user clicking on the "install"/"update" button on the Market homepage in the browser. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: How would you know the link behind the update button for your app in the market?

Comment: Post your answer here if you are successful.

Answer (score 2):

I've had an app, post its version to a server and if didn't match the current version listed on the server, fires an intent that takes the user right to the market - can either allow them to cancel and continue, or stop them from using the app until they upgrade.  I think it stopped them by bringing up a webview fullscreen to the market url and they can't hide it to access the app.

Comment: This approach has a problem, as I explain in another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835419/how-to-force-update-on-an-app-when-backend-changes-requires-an-updated-app